# Will this coding style result in a memory leak

Tags: c#, silverlight, event-handling, mvvm-light

Following the MVVM pattern I'm trying to wire up the display of a child window by the View in response to a request from the View Model.

Using the MVVM-Light Messenger the View will Register for the request to display the child window in the constructor of the View as so:

```
InitializeComponent();
Messenger.Default.Register<EditorInfo>(this, (editorData) =>
{
    ChildWindow editWindow = new EditWindow();
    editWindow.Closed += (s, args) =>
    {
        if (editWindow.DialogResult == true)
            // Send data back to VM
        else
           // Send 'Cancel' back to VM
   };

   editWindow.Show();
});
```

Does subscribing to the ChildWindow Closed event using a Lambda cause problems for garbage collection.  Or put it another way, when (if ever) will the editWindow become unreferenced and so a candidate for garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`editWindow` will keep a reference to `this`, but nothing will have a reference  to `editWindow`, so it will eventually be garbage collected, and the reference to `this` will be discarded. So it shouldn't cause any memory leak...

If you want to be sure there will be no problem, you can unsubscribe from the event:

```
InitializeComponent();
Messenger.Default.Register<EditorInfo>(this, (editorData) =>
{
    ChildWindow editWindow = new EditWindow();
    EventHandler handler = (s, args) =>
    {
        editWindow.Closed -= handler;
        if (editWindow.DialogResult == true)
            // Send data back to VM
        else
           // Send 'Cancel' back to VM
   };

   editWindow.Closed += handler;

   editWindow.Show();
});
```